# What happens in Canada if a divorce invalidates in Iran?

Tags: canada, fraud, marriage, divorce, criminal-record

Thank you for reading this and your help.

A man, let's say mr. X has divorced his wife (with some fraud) in Iran and move to Canada with a work permit. 
The woman, let's name her Ms. Y, has invalidated the divorce in Iran since it was obtained with forgery. Will this affect X in Canada? How?

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote?! If there is something to improve I would be glad to know.

Comment: Please do not be mean with down voting. If there is something that can be improved, you can either leave a comment or edit. Why down vote?!

Comment: Stop asking questions here that require a team of lawyers and the law enforcement of multiple countries to resolve. They are clearly off-topic, and this one in particular is extremely broad, with four different things happening that all require separate handling.

Comment: @Nij If it was easy, Googling it would answer me. Sites like this are for seeking help from people who are knowledgeable and want to contribute. If you can't or don't want to help, fine. Just no need to down vote so others who actually want to help would not get to see the question. Thank you.

Comment: It's not about whether the answer can be found on Google, it's that the answer for you requires (by law in many jurisdictions) that a lawyer be the one to give it to you, and you are further asking about things that only police authorities can even attempt. You have fundamentally misunderstood what Stack Exchange is for and what is within bounds for it, and for what voting means.

Comment: @Nij Can you explain more? Like what does the police have to do with the divorce invalidation? Or in what aspect have I not understood the purpose of Stack Exchange?

Comment: If you really have to ask that, you don't seem to understand what you're even asking. *How can I get someone deported?* - that's not up to you. It's on the investigative and prosecution sections of the country's judicial system. That's just one of the major issues with the question here. Stack Exchange is for creating a set of questions that require expert answers, curated to ensure their quality, to help general audience in the future. Not for replacing individual professional advice to specific situations that nobody else is going to be involved in.

Comment: @Nij This question is simply about a divorce invalidation!! It has nothing to do with deportation!!!

Comment: [At the time of writing your comment, yes, it did](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/52124/2) (edit histories are annotated and public). Your original question linked directly to another where you ask the same thing, how to get another country to deport someone. The question is now just as broad, but additionally vague and undirected.

Comment: @Nij Read the topic and the main body. It is clearly about divorce invalidation and have always been. I just mentioned a couple of options, I am not a lawyer after all. Deport is only one possible outcome to my mind. Like many others. And that another question was for further detail just in case anyone needs to see the big picture!! That is why it is ANOTHER question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacting an immigration agency in Canada, who handle Iranian immigration cases, I got this information:

Then he has lied on his immigration/visa application.
If the divorce invalidates, it means he has been married. Then stating his status as single is a lie with which he cannot get away with. It might not end up in deportation necessarily, but it is not very unlikely either.

Also should thank @Hilmar for his comments on stack exchange.

Edit:

I add this edit only to help future readers, I hope it will come handy to someone.

1. There is a center called Justice Access Center which offers legal advises, mediation and some other services. They offer pro bono services. You can reach them [here](https://www2.gov.bc.ca).
2. There is an organization for Iranian women in Ontario. They also are very helpful and have access to precious resources. You can reach them [here](https://iwontario.com/).

I hope these can save some women from abuse or threat.